# iTunes Store is unavailable

Tags: ios, itunes-store, books

Recently I am downloading movies from iTunes Store and books from iBooks Store. But one annoying thing that I've ran into these days are The Movie/iBooks store is unavailable. This is happening for a week now. I've checked the [Apple's Service Availability Page](http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/) but it says that everything is available. Here are screenshots:

[image: Movies Store unavailable]

[image: iBooks Store unavailable]

This is happening on an iPhone 6s and iPad Pro if it does matter. My Apple ID country is China and my location is in China.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

China blocked the iTunes store and iBook store due to it's political issues with Apple.

[Update] VPN doesn't help, it's account based not location based.

Comment: Thanks, I manage to get it to work after switching to one of my US account.

Comment: Your welcome! So it's account based and not location based. Or did you use a VPN connection?

Comment: It's account based. I tried VPN with the Chinese account and it still don't work. Switch to US account and it worked instantly.